# NoSQL & AdHoc Queries - Millions of Rows

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I currently run a MySQL-powered website where users promote advertisements and gain revenue every time someone completes one. We log every time someone views an ad ("impression"), every time a user clicks an add ("click"), and every time someone completes an ad ("lead").

Since we get so much traffic, we have millions of records in each of these respective tables. We then have to query these tables to let users see how much they have earned, so we end up performing multiple queries on tables with millions and millions of rows multiple times in one request, hundreds of times concurrently.

We're looking to move away from MySQL and to a key-value store or something along those lines. We need something that will let us store all these millions of rows, query them in milliseconds, and MOST IMPORTANTLY, use adhoc queries where we can query any single column, so we could do things like:

FROM leads WHERE country = 'US' AND user_id = 501   (the NoSQL equivalent, obviously)

FROM clicks WHERE ad_id = 1952 AND user_id = 200 AND country = 'GB'

etc.

Does anyone have any good suggestions? I was considering MongoDB or CouchDB but I'm not sure if they can handle querying millions of records multiple times a second and the type of adhoc queries we need.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: 1.) Are there rather several hundred records per user, or does every user have just a very few? 2.) Do most of the queries contain a user_id condition? 3.) Are stats across the entire dataset time-critical? (probably nothing the user gets to see) 4.) Do you need the result set to be sorted (e.g. alphabetically by country)? Either way, you should give the upcoming [ArangoDB v2.6](http://arangodb.org/) a try!

Answer (score 5):

With those requirements, you are probably better off sticking with SQL and setting up replication/clustering if you are running into load issues. You can set up indexing on a document database so that those queries are possible, but you don't really gain anything over your current system.

NoSQL systems generally improve performance by leaving out some of the more complex features of relational systems. This means that they will only help if your scenario doesn't require those features. Running ad hoc queries on tabular data is exactly what SQL was designed for.

Comment: +1 Right tool for the right job. The people writing the paychecks often ask discomforting questions. They do not care if their question is "scalable" or not. Relational databases indeed excel at answering any conceivable (well-formed) question without prior warning.

Comment: Agree right tool for the job. But writing a MapReduce program do ad-hoc things isnt that complex once you understand it and get past the learning curve. Writing Ad-hoc analysis jobs is great, you get to keep all your data in the one place, dont need to play charades with data warehousing (i.e. moving old data out etc). With SQL partitioning you can go back a few yrs before performance degrades, with a well designed NoSQL system you can query decades of data & get a answer in a few hrs not tomorrow, which looks awesome and makes the business happy &isnt the hastle with reporting on old data..

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB's map/reduce is *incremental* which means it only processes a document once and stores the results.

Let's assume, for a moment, that CouchDB is the slowest database in the world. Your first query with millions of rows takes, maybe, 20 hours. That sounds terrible. However, your second query, your third query, your fourth query, and your hundredth query will take 50 milliseconds, perhaps 100 including HTTP and network latency.

You could say CouchDB fails the benchmarks but gets honors in the school of hard knocks.

I would not worry about performance, but rather if CouchDB can satisfy your ad-hoc query requirements. CouchDB wants to know what queries will occur, so it can do the hard work up-front before the query arrives. When the query does arrive, the answer is already prepared and out it goes!

All of your examples **are** possible with CouchDB. A so-called *merge-join* (lots of equality conditions) is no problem. However CouchDB cannot support multiple inequality queries simultaneously. You cannot ask CouchDB, in a single query, for users between age 18-40 who also clicked fewer than 10 times.

The nice thing about CouchDB's HTTP and Javascript interface is, it's easy to do a quick feasibility study. I suggest you try it out!

Comment: Also, Couchbase is working on a hybrid CouchDB/Membase server. Membase, the database that runs Farmville, is admired for (among other things) sub-millisecond query results. This hybrid product does not exist today however.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Does MongoDB have the same issue with the first query taking a while? Also, does it take a while the first time you run a query with certain columns, certain parameters for the columns, or just every time the data is updated? Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 CouchDb indexing is not fast. But the index is built incrementally and, once built, the query will be very fast.

Comment: Indeed. @Marcello, note my reply to your comment in the other (strangely similar) question today. It *is* possible to update a design document and build an index from scratch with no downtime. Unfortunately you have to be your own toolsmith a little bit.

Comment: How is MongoDB indexing, or will it not have this issue?

Comment: @Paul Bakoyiannis, unfortunately I am not sure, perhaps a MongoDB expert can chime in.

Answer (score 2):

Most people would probably recommend **MongoDB** for a tracking/analytic system like this, for good reasons. You should read the [„MongoDB for Real-Time Analytics”](http://books.google.com/books?id=BQS33CxGid4C&pg=PA169) chapter from the „MongoDB Definitive Guide” book. Depending on the size of your data and scaling needs, you could get all the performance, schema-free storage and ad-hoc querying features. You will need to decide for yourself if issues with durability and unpredictability of the system are risky for you or not.

For a simpler tracking system, **Redis** would be a very good choice, offering rich functionality, blazing speed and real durability. To get a feel how such a system would be implemented in Redis, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/974306). The downside is, that you'd need to define all the „indices” by yourself, not gain them for „free”, as is the case with MongoDB. Nevertheless, there's no free lunch, and MongoDB indices are definitely not a free lunch.

I think you should have a look into how **ElasticSearch** would enable you:

- Blazing speed
- Schema-free storage
- Sharding and distributed architecture
- Powerful analytic primitives in the form of [facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/)
- Easy implementation of „sliding window”-type of data storage with index aliases

It is in heart a „fulltext search engine”, but don't get yourself confused by that. Read the [„Data Visualization with ElasticSearch and Protovis“](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/05/13/data-visualization-with-elasticsearch-and-protovis.html) article for real world use case of ElasticSearch as a data mining engine.

Have a look on [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/karmi/your-data-your-search-elasticsearch-euruko-2011/52) for real world use case for „sliding window” scenario.

There are many client libraries for ElasticSearch available, such as [Tire](http://karmi.github.com/tire/) for Ruby, so it's easy to get off the ground with a prototype quickly.

For the record (with all due respect to @jhs :), based on my experience, I cannot imagine an implementation where **Couchdb** is a feasible and useful option. It would be an awesome backup storage for your data, though.

Answer (score 1):

If your working set can fit in the memory, and you index the right fields in the document, you'd be all set. Your ask is not something very typical and I am sure with proper hardware, right collection design (denormalize!) and indexing you should be good to go. Read up on Mongo querying, and use `explain()` to test the queries. Stay away from `IN` and `NOT IN` clauses that'd be my suggestion.

Comment: +1 "Proper hardware" -- an excellent point! Fantastic software *can* run on humdrum hardware, but disappointing test results shouldn't be pinned on the software.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your data sets. The number one rule to NoSQL design is to define your query scenarios first. Once you really understand how you want to query the data then you can look into the various NoSQL solutions out there. The default unit of distribution is key. Therefore you need to remember that you need to be able to split your data between your node machines effectively otherwise you will end up with a horizontally scalable system with all the work still being done on one node (albeit better queries depending on the case).

You also need to think back to CAP theorem, most NoSQL databases are eventually consistent (CP or AP) while traditional Relational DBMS are CA. This will impact the way you handle data and creation of certain things, for example key generation can be come trickery.

Also remember than in some systems such as HBase there is no indexing concept. All your indexes will need to be built by your application logic and any updates and deletes will need to be managed as such. With Mongo you can actually create indexes on fields and query them relatively quickly, there is also the possibility to integrate Solr with Mongo. You don’t just need to query by ID in Mongo like you do in HBase which is a column family (aka Google BigTable style database) where you essentially have nested key-value pairs.

So once again it comes to your data, what you want to store, how you plan to store it, and most importantly how you want to access it. The Lily project looks very promising. The work I am involved with we take a large amount of data from the web and we store it, analyse it, strip it down, parse it, analyse it, stream it, update it etc etc. We dont just use one system but many which are best suited to the job at hand. For this process we use different systems at different stages as it gives us fast access where we need it, provides the ability to stream and analyse data in real-time and importantly, keep track of everything as we go (as data loss in a prod system is a big deal) . I am using Hadoop, HBase, Hive, MongoDB, Solr, MySQL and even good old text files. Remember that to productionize a system using these technogies is a bit harder than installing MySQL on a server, some releases are not as stable and you really need to do your testing first. At the end of the day it really depends on the level of business resistance and the mission-critical nature of your system.

Another path that no one thus far has mentioned is NewSQL - i.e. Horizontally scalable RDBMSs... There are a few out there like MySQL cluster (i think) and VoltDB which may suit your cause.

Again it comes to understanding your data and the access patterns, NoSQL systems are also Non-Rel i.e. non-relational and are there for better suit to non-relational data sets. If your data is inherently relational and you need some SQL query features that really need to do things like Cartesian products (aka joins) then you may well be better of sticking with Oracle and investing some time in indexing, sharding and performance tuning.

My advice would be to actually play around with a few different systems. However for your use case I think a Column Family database may be the best solution, I think there are a few places which have implemented similar solutions to very similar problems (I think the NYTimes is using HBase to monitor user page clicks). Another great example is Facebook and like, they are using HBase for this. There is a really good article here which may help you along your way and further explain some points above. http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/22/facebooks-new-realtime-analytics-system-hbase-to-process-20.html

Final point would be that NoSQL systems are not the be all and end all. Putting your data into a NoSQL database does not mean its going to perform any better than MySQL, Oracle or even text files... For example see this blog post: http://mysqldba.blogspot.com/2010/03/cassandra-is-my-nosql-solution-but.html

I'd have a look at;

**MongoDB** - Document - CP

**CouchDB** - Document - AP

**Redis** - In memory key-value (not column family) - CP

**Cassandra** - Column Family - Available & Partition Tolerant (AP)

**HBase** - Column Family - Consistent & Partition Tolerant (CP)

**Hadoop/Hive** - Also have a look at Hadoop streaming...

**Hypertable** - Another CF CP DB.

**VoltDB** - A really good looking product, a relation database that is distributed and might work for your case (may be an easier move). They also seem to provide enterprise support which may be more suited for a prod env (i.e. give business users a sense of security).

Any way thats my 2c. Playing around with the systems is really the only way your going to find out what really works for your case.